# regular expressions with Javascripts

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to clean up angular code to send it later to jsPDF.
jsPDF usually fails when not recognize HTML code is found, so I am trying to get rid of it.

So far the expression would it be something like

```
'<code>'.replace(/ng-\w+="(\w|\d\s)+"/,'')
```

This is useful for simple things but I need a more elaborated expressions and I haven't been able to come across it.

```
ng-\w+=" 
#Finds expressions like ng-if, ng-model, ng-class, etc

(\w|\d\s)+ 
#This expressions only accepts spaces, numbers and digits
```

What  I really need is to get all the content in between the double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Why not use DOMParser instead, like this? Better not to try to parse HTML with regex

```js
const html = `
<div id="myid" class="myclass" ng-if="ngif attribute" ng-model="ngmodel attribute" ng-class="ngclass attribute">content</div>
<div ng-if="another ngif attribute">content 2</div>
`;
const parsedDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
const attributesToRemove = [
  'ng-if',
  'ng-model',
  'ng-class',
];
attributesToRemove.forEach((attribName) => {
  parsedDoc.querySelectorAll('[' + attribName + ']')
    .forEach((elm) => elm.removeAttribute(attribName));
});
console.log(parsedDoc.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answer...

You could use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), then use a [`treeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) to iterate through all of the nodes and remove any attribute that starts with `ng-`:

```js
const html = `
<div id="myid" class="myclass" ng-if="ngif attribute" ng-model="ngmodel attribute" ng-class="ngclass attribute">content</div>
<div ng-if="another ngif attribute">content 2</div>
`;
const el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");

var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  el,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
  { acceptNode: function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; } },
  false
);

var nodeList = [];

while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    Array.apply(null, treeWalker.currentNode.attributes).
        filter(a => a.name.startsWith('ng-')).
        forEach((attr, index) => {
            treeWalker.currentNode.removeAttribute(attr.name);
        });
}
console.log(el.documentElement.querySelector('body').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this `/ng-\w+=("|').*?\1/`